# Limit process ram but force swap instead of kill

Tags: linux, memory, centos, process, memory-limit

I am currently quite frustrated with **meteor**. I am going to make my own telescope modification via the official repository on my hosting service of choice. The only problem is that meteor **builds** the app again **on every startup** and takes quite the amount of RAM while all my processes have a **hard limit** of **`600MB`**. That is quickly exceeded by meteor and it gets killed. Now when I try to start it again it starts all from zero and thus gets killed over and over again.

Now I wondered if it would be possible to wrap something similar to the existing limitation around the `node` process that doesn't kill it but **swaps out** as much as possible, in the best case to a **file**. I don't care if it will take a whole lot longer to build, it's for development.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: VMMap allows you to flush the virtual memory of an application to disk. It must be using a Windows API. May be you can search for the same and write a wrapper exe to keep a watch on meteor and flush as needed

Comment: @GaneshR. Sorry, forgot to say that it's a linux server. CentOS, to be specific.